# Get Object/Material Index of Completely Transparent Objects

Tags: materials, transparency, render-passes

OK, I know the question is kinda usual. My problem is I want some objects in a scene completely transparent/invisible (in most of the render passes) while I still can show it in either material or object index pass. I would avoid duplicate the scene because it's quite large and complicated and the less labor, the merrier.

Comment: Fully transparent material does not give material index pass, but partially transparent does. Maybe it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

In Cycles you can adjust the Alpha Threshold for the Render Layer to adjust how layers are affected by transparency. Setting the Alpha Threshold to 0.000 will result in all objects - even those that are completely transparent - affecting the Index passes (as well as the Z, Normal, UV, and Vector passes).

[image: Alpha Threshold]